# Как вывестив в Grid ExtJS изображение ?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте!
Медленно но верно изучаю **ExtJS**. Возникла небольшая проблемка...
Как вывести в ячейку таблицы (**Grid**) изображение.

```
grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    border: false,
    store: myStore,
    layout:'fit',
    activeSelection: null,
    columns: [
        {
            text: "Логотип",
            tooltip: 'Тут нужна картинка не шире 70px',
            width: 70,
            dataIndex: 'logo'
        }, {
            text: "Название",
            tooltip: 'Наименование картинки',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }
        // тут ещё несколько колонок с фиксированной шириной
    ]
});
```

***logo*** содержит имя файла изображения. Предположим что все изображения лежат относительно корня в папке */res/img/forGrid/*.

Как вместо имени файла вывести изображение с соответствующим именем в определенной папке?

**PS**:
Предполагаю, что нужно для этой колонки задать ***renderer***, но не пойму как это сделать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути: [Column renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer)

```
    {
        text: "Логотип",
        tooltip: 'Тут нужна картинка не шире 70px',
        width: 70,
        dataIndex: 'logo'
        renderer: function(value){
            return '<img src="/res/img/forGrid/' + value + '">';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Как то не подумал что будет так просто....  
Спасибо!

Comment: (: не успел, еще можно в базе хранить base64 тело файла изображения. Тогда файлы не надо на серваке хранить они лежать в бд, а сервак клиенту шлет тока тело.

Comment: Можно, но зачем?  
Файлы предпочитаю не хранить в бд - на то они и файлы.  
Тем более что мне нужно несколько вариантов изображений - оригинальное и два, а то и три обработанных изображения (либо сделанные квадратными и приведенными к определенному размеру, либо ещё как-то - есть несколько разных задач). В итого у меня будет куча лишней для бд информации.  
Поэтому файлы предпочитаю дергать (если нет какой-то особой необходимости) как файлы, не привлекая бд и php (или что-то другое на чем написана северная часть).

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя сразу указать вместо имени файла картинки - тег картинки `<img src="myimage.jpeg"/>`

Comment: Сразу нельзя - не резон хранить в БД имя файла с тегом, к тому же если путь у всех изображений таблицы один и тот же...  
Да это будут и лишние данные передаваемые с сервера...  
Так что необходимо

    <img src="/res/img/forGrid/{image}" width="70px" /> 

подставить при выводе данных в таблицу...  
Если, конечно же, изображение так выводится в таблицу...

Comment: я не говорю хранить их в базе) я говорю генерировать поле на стороне сервера после получения данных с базы)

Comment: В таком случае с сервера будет передаваться строка длиннее в 2-3 раза оригинальной для каждой записи. Причем как минимум половина содержимого этой строки будет идентична строкам остальных записей.  
К тому же значение данного поля редактируется в *Dialog*... А это значит что для редактирование мне нужно парсить строку..  
К сожалению такой подход я считаю не приемлемым!